# How can the CNN model be trained with K-Fold Cross Validation

Tags: deep-learning, cross-validation, training-data, conv-neural-network

First of all, thank you in advance for the answers to come. I am confused about the use of K-Fold Cross Validation (CV) with CNN.

When working with CV under normal conditions, as seen in the link below, the original dataset is first split as test and training.

https://miro.medium.com/max/875/1*pJ5jQHPfHDyuJa4-7LR11Q.png

Then, the training dataset is divided into training and validation in the K cycle according to the determined K value. In short, if we say K = 5, our training is repeated 5 times, and each time a newly trained model is formed.

Question 1: How can we calculate the overall training-validation accuracy and loss values of 5 different models. Do we need to add up and average the success of all models?

Question 2: We separated the TEST data set from the original data set at the beginning of the training. How can we test the TEST data set on 5 different models? Should we test on 5 models then get their average accuracy or should we test only on the most successful model?